# How can I read user inputs from a dynamically created form in flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I want to create a dynamic input form and read the user inputs back when a button ("Submit") is pressed, what is the best way (a good way) to do this?

I have tried creating a dynamic form with a FieldList but I was unable to get the values from the user.
This is (hopefully all of) the relevant code:

**forms.py**

```
class EntryForm(Form):
   field = StringField()

class DynamicForm(FlaskForm):
   parameter = FieldList(FormField(EntryForm), min_entries=1)
   submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route("/new", method=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_form():
   form = DynamicForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
      values = form.parameter #This does not work as intended.
      do_stuff(values)
      return redirect(url_for('index'))

   parameter = utils.get_parameter()
   return render_template('dynamic_form.html', form=form, parameter=parameter)
```

where *utils.get_parameter()* returns an unknown list of parameters. Or to be precise the function expects a parameter and returns a list based on this paramater, but I have omitted this here.

**dynamic_form.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% macro render_field(item) %}
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-control-label">{{ item.label }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="{{ item.name }}" class="form-control" value="{{ item.value }}"/>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="content-section">
      <form method="POST" action="">
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
         <fieldset class ="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Parameter</legend>
            {% for item in form.parameter %}
               {{ render_field(item) }}}
            {% endfor %}
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I assume it is because the validate_on_submit() is called after the form is constructed (again) and thus it does not contain the form fields, and especially not the user inputs. Is there a way to prevent this "data loss" or is this a completely wrong approach?
Also, please let me know if information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to validate the form when the page first loads.  Try this first:

```
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
    values = form.parameter 
    do_stuff(values)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Next, notice that you are redirecting them to your view for `def index():`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your response, validate_on_submit() does exactly that as far as I know, it only validates if the request method was "POST". And the redirect does not matter, important is, that I have the values for the _do_stuff(values)_ call.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not change the behaviour. The only question I have is, how to get the values from the inputs of the form? Currently if I call `form.parameter.entries` below the validate_on_submit() it returns just the dummy _parameter_ which I defined in the _DynamicForm_ class.